How can I formalize better this proof that angular momentum is conserved for a small impulse?
The book I am studying is discussing Lagrange stability of circular orbits, which assumes fixed angular momentum ${\bf L}$, hence in an introductory paragraph explains why, when studying stability of a circular orbit, we can neglect as a first approximation the variation of angular momentum.
The discussion goes like this (note that the two unit vectors ${\bf e}_r$ and ${\bf e}_\phi$ have been introduced previously as the unit orthogonal coordinate vectors in polar coordinates):

Suppose that the point particle moves along a circular orbit and receives a small impulse $\delta {\bf p}$. Since the resulting variation $\delta {\bf L}$ of the angular momentum satisfies $\delta {\bf L} = {\bf r} \times \delta {\bf p}$, the component of $\delta {\bf p}$ which is parallel to the angular momentum ${\bf L}$ has the effect of slightly altering $|{\bf L}|$ and the plane of the orbit. The component of $\delta {\bf p}$ orthogonal to ${\bf L}$ can be decomposed into a vector parallel to ${\bf e}_r$ ---which does not change ${\bf L}$ --- and one parallel to ${\bf e}_\phi$, changing the absolute value but not the direction of the angular momentum. The orbit therefore always stays in a plane close to the plane of the initial reference circular orbit, and in studying stability we can as a first approximation neglect the variation of ${\bf L}$.

What does this mean? As Pato Galmarini explains below $\delta {\bf L}$ is an infinitesimal of same order as order as $\delta {\bf p}$, but I would like to have some more rigorous proof as I cannot understand what the text is trying to convey.
Reference book: Analytical Mechanics: An Introduction by Fasano and Marmi, p. 188.
https://books.google.it/books?id=DDG0IMpuUoQC&lpg=PA125&hl=it&pg=PA188#v=onepage&q&f=true

Related: Lyapunov stability of circular orbits

FWIW, in this answer I show the variation in the specific angular momentum of Halley's comet, using data from JPL. As you can see, the variation is relatively small. (My Sage script can calculate the angular momentum for any Solar System body that Horizons knows, relative to any major body).

In general, $\delta \mathbf{L} = \delta \mathbf{r} \times \mathbf{p} + \mathbf{r} \times \delta \mathbf{p}$, which in this case becomes $\delta \mathbf{L} = \mathbf{r} \times \delta \mathbf{p} = \mathbf{r} \times \delta \mathbf{p}_\phi$, where $\delta \mathbf{p}_\phi$ is the non-radial component of the momentum variation, as explained in the text.
We thus see that $\delta |\mathbf{L}| = r\delta|\mathbf{p}_\phi| \sim \delta|\mathbf{p}_\phi|$ is infinitesimal, and IN A FIRST APPROXIMATION can be neglected. Of course, this is not true, and you might want to iteratively refine your calculations to account for the actual change of $L$.
Because of this, in a first approximation, we can only consider an impulse in the radial direction, i.e. the trajectory will be modified radially without modifying the angular momentum.

thanks for your reply. i don't understand your last paragraph. we are indeed mentioning non radial components of momentum variation. so why are you saying that you are only considering a radial impulse? that inpulse, small or big, would not change the momentum anyways, by definition.

there is also a few typos that you would like to review

In a first approximation, we can focus only on the radial component of the impulse as the non-radial one would change the angular momentum, while we are approximating that $L$ remains unchanged. This would simplify any later computation.

I think that your reply is the more helpful so far. would you like to have a look at my summary answer, and tell me me if it makes sense?

@ebenezer Sounds good!

Summary of the changes in $\delta L$ for a decomposed $\delta p$
To be a bit more complete, here is a mathematical overview how $\delta p$ concretely changes the $L$.

Parallel to $\mathbf{L}$: $\delta p_L = \delta p \cdot \hat{\mathbf{L}}$. This component changes the magnitude of $\mathbf{L}$ and slightly tilts the plane of the orbit, affecting the orbit’s inclination. Effect: Change in both $|\mathbf{L}|$ and the plane of the orbit.

Tangential Direction ($\mathbf{e}_\phi$): $\delta p_\phi = \delta p \cdot \mathbf{e}_\phi$. The cross product $ \mathbf{r} \times \delta p_\phi $ changes the magnitude of $\mathbf{L}$, but not its direction. Effect: Change in $|\mathbf{L}|$, but direction of $\mathbf{L}$ remains constant.

Radial Direction ($\mathbf{e}_r$): $\delta p_r = \delta p \cdot \mathbf{e}_r$. Since $\mathbf{r} \parallel \mathbf{e}_r$, the cross product $ \mathbf{r} \times \delta p_r = 0 $. Effect: No change in $\mathbf{L}$, $\delta L = 0$.


So concluding we have:
$$ \delta \mathbf{L} = \mathbf{r} \times \left( \delta p_L \hat{\mathbf{L}} + \delta p_\phi \mathbf{e}_\phi + \delta p_r \mathbf{e}_r \right)  = \mathbf{r} \times \left( \delta p_L \hat{\mathbf{L}} + \delta p_\phi \mathbf{e}_\phi \right)  $$
So if we substitute this into a perturbative expansion of the angular momentum we get:
$$ \mathbf{L} \approx \mathbf{L}_0 + \epsilon \mathbf{L}_1 + \epsilon^2 \mathbf{L}_2 + \epsilon^3 \mathbf{L}_3 + \dots $$
Here:

$\mathbf{L}_0$ is the unperturbed angular momentum,
$\epsilon \mathbf{L}_1$ is the first-order correction due to the small perturbation $ \delta \mathbf{p} $. So in this case $ \mathbf{L}_1 = \delta \mathbf{L} $

So then we get in first approximation:
$$ \mathbf{L} \approx \mathbf{L}_0 + \epsilon\mathbf{L}_1 = \mathbf{L}_0 + \epsilon \delta \mathbf{L} $$
$$ \mathbf{L} \approx \mathbf{L}_0 + \epsilon \left( \mathbf{r} \times \delta p_L \hat{\mathbf{L}} + \mathbf{r} \times \delta p_\phi \mathbf{e}_\phi \right) =  \mathbf{L}_0 + \left( \mathbf{r} \times \underline{\epsilon \delta p_L} \hat{\mathbf{L}} + \mathbf{r} \times \underline{\epsilon \delta p_\phi} \mathbf{e}_\phi \right) $$
Since in first approximation we can say $ \epsilon \delta p \approx 0 $, since this is an infinitesimal to the second power, we get in this first approximation:
$$ \mathbf{L} \approx \mathbf{L}_0 $$
Nature of infinitesimals
Perhaps this question is more about the nature of infinitesimals than about the physical problem of orbits. A $\Delta p$ will definitely change the orbit, but a $\delta p$ will not change the orbit in first approximation because the $L(p)$ relation is linear. So the problem can be restated as;
'If we produce an infinitesimal $ \delta p $, can the resultant $ \delta L $ be neglected in the first approximation?'
For some functions, this is possible, while for others, it is not. For the angular momentum function $ L(p) $, this is possible. An example where this is not possible is the following:
For the function $ f(x) = \frac{1}{x} $, an infinitesimal change $ dx $ results in a differential $ df $ given by $ df = -\frac{1}{x^2} dx $. When $ x $ is small, the derivative $ f'(x) = -\frac{1}{x^2} $ becomes very large. This means that even a tiny $ dx $ can cause a significant change in $ f(x) $, making $ df $ non-infinitesimal. Thus, in this case, an infinitesimal change in $ x $ does not produce an infinitesimal change in $ f(x) $ of the same order.
In contrast, for the angular momentum function $ L(p) = r \times p $, the situation is different. Given a small impulse $ \delta p $, the resulting change in angular momentum is $ \delta L = r \times \delta p $. Since the cross product is linear in both terms, for small $ \delta p $, the change in angular momentum $ \delta L $ remains of the same infinitesimal order as $ \delta p $.
This means that in first-order approximations, the variation in $ L $ due to a small perturbation in $ p $ can be neglected without introducing significant errors in stability analysis. The orbit remains in a plane close to the original circular orbit, and the stability condition relies on the fact that small deviations do not cause large changes in angular momentum. Hence, for circular orbits, neglecting the variation of $ L $ in the first approximation is a valid assumption because $ \delta L $ remains small in proportion to the perturbation $ \delta p $, unlike the example with $ f(x) = \frac{1}{x} $."
In the context of a Taylor expansion, $ \delta \mathbf{L} $ represents the first-order change in the angular momentum due to a small perturbation, and it corresponds to the linear term in the Taylor expansion.
Taylor Expansion of $ \mathbf{L} $:
If we expand $ \mathbf{L} $ as a function of a small perturbation parameter $ \epsilon $, the Taylor expansion would look like this:
$$
\mathbf{L}(\epsilon) \approx \mathbf{L}(0) + \epsilon \frac{d\mathbf{L}}{d\epsilon} \Big|_{\epsilon=0} + \frac{\epsilon^2}{2!} \frac{d^2\mathbf{L}}{d\epsilon^2} \Big|_{\epsilon=0} + \dots
$$

$ \mathbf{L}(0) $ is the unperturbed angular momentum, denoted $ \mathbf{L}_0 $.
$ \epsilon \frac{d\mathbf{L}}{d\epsilon} \Big|_{\epsilon=0} $ is the first-order term, which corresponds to the first derivative of $ \mathbf{L} $ with respect to $ \epsilon $.

In this Taylor expansion, the term $ \delta \mathbf{L} $ would be equivalent to the first derivative of $ \mathbf{L} $ with respect to the perturbation parameter $ \epsilon $:
$$
\delta \mathbf{L} = \frac{d\mathbf{L}}{d\epsilon} \Big|_{\epsilon=0}.
$$
This term represents the first-order change in angular momentum due to the perturbation.

thanks for the extended reply. one thing that is not clear to me is the following. if we say that $\delta L$ is an inf of the same order as $\delta p$, why don't we have linear terms in the perturbative expansion? In other words, rather than $\mathbf{L}_1 = \delta \mathbf{L}$ shouldn't we have $\epsilon \mathbf{L}_1 = \delta \mathbf{L}$, i.e. $\mathbf{L}_1$ should not be an infinitesimal as well, if my understanding of the $\epsilon$ expansion is correct,i.e. like a taylor series expansion (i don't know perturbative methods at all).

In a Taylor expansion, $\delta \mathbf{L} $ is the first-order term representing the linear response of the angular momentum $ \mathbf{L} $ to a small perturbation. The Taylor series is $  \mathbf{L}(\epsilon) \approx \mathbf{L}(0) + \epsilon \frac{d\mathbf{L}}{d\epsilon} \Big|{\epsilon=0} + \frac{\epsilon^2}{2!} \frac{d^2\mathbf{L}}{d\epsilon^2} \Big|{\epsilon=0} + \dots $. Here, $ \delta \mathbf{L} = \frac{d\mathbf{L}}{d\epsilon} \Big|_{\epsilon=0} = \epsilon \mathbf{L}_1 $  is the first-order change in angular momentum. Does that make sense?

yes, this makes sense to me. what does not make sense to me is the magic by which the second terms becomes a second order infinitesimal in your expansion :) by multiplying by $\epsilon$ and by $\delta$. If the variations of L and p  have the same order, the instinct tells me that 1) $\epsilon$ and $\delta$ are the same thing 2)$L_1$ should not be an infinitesimal (i.e. contain $\delta$) if you put in the expansion $\epsilon L_1$ as the first order term 3) you are then counting the perturbation twice. otherwise it does not hold any more that the variations of L and p are of the same order, no?

I made a mistake, I can't edit it anymore, but it should be $ \delta L = L_1 $. We have a product of 2 infinitesimals, so that is an infinitesimal to order 2; you can neglect these in the first approximation. The first approximation only takes into account infinitesimals to order 1.

thats the point! why should we have an infinitesimal of order 2 as perturbation of $L$ as we said that the perturbation of $L$ and of $p$ have the same order? I was referring to the perturbative expansion of your answer not of the comment. It is strange to me to have as expansion $L_0+\epsilon\delta L + ...$ as it is not the same order as $\delta p$. if $\delta L$ represents a first order change (i.e. an infinitesimal change), it cannot be also a first derivative (i.e. a proportionality ration that is not an infinitesimal itself).

You believe that "$ δL$ is an infinitesimal of order higher than $δp$". I am not sure why you believe that, they are of the same order in $δv$. What the text is trying to explain intuitively without going into math details, is that a small change in $p$ will not trigger a large change in $L$, because of the intuitive reasons explained. It could have been, instead, in a different dynamical system, that a small change in p would shift the orbit into a qualitatively different one. However, this is not happening here. That is, it is not like the example of a pencil balancing on its tip, in which different small perturbations will end up with the pencil falling into completely different final states, something called unstable equilibrium.

thanks for your comments. on the other hand, even if $\delta L$ and $\delta p$ have the same order, not all circular orbits are Lagrange stable. Indeed, the definition of Lagrange stability is stated after this paragraph, and it uses the fact that $L$ is kept constant when comparing close orbits. I can cope with this, if this is just the definition, what I don't get is why and how the paragraph tries to justify this assumption.

note (more to myself). even if the orbit "diverges" the angular momentum will be conserved.

Overview
If total momentum is conserved between two bodies due to Newton's 3rd law, then angular momentum will also be conserved as the impulse will act and react on the same line of action.
Background
At some instant, an object is observed from the origin at position vector $\boldsymbol{r}$ and with linear momentum $\boldsymbol{p}$. The objects angular momentum as seen by the origin is $$ \boldsymbol{L} = \boldsymbol{r} \times \boldsymbol{p} \tag{1}$$

This signifies that linear momentum $\boldsymbol{p}$ has a 3D line of action in space, and if you slide the vector anywhere along this line it will result in the same angular momentum.
You prove that with $$\boldsymbol{L} = (\boldsymbol{r} + \kappa\, \boldsymbol{p}) \times \boldsymbol{p} = \boldsymbol{r} \times \boldsymbol{p} $$ as any arbitrary  scalar value $\kappa$ keeps the vector $\kappa\,\boldsymbol{p}$ parallel to $\boldsymbol{p}$ and thus absorbed by the cross product.

The line of action can be recovered from the pair of vectors $(\boldsymbol{p},\,\boldsymbol{L})$, which are also called the Plücker coordinates of the line. This is done by noting that the point on the line closest to the origin is $$\boldsymbol{r}_0 = \frac{ \boldsymbol{p} \times \boldsymbol{L} } { \| \boldsymbol{p} \|^2 } \tag{2}$$
The proof is by calculating the angular momentum from $\boldsymbol{r}_0$ and showing that it equals $\boldsymbol{L}.
$$\require{cancel} \begin{aligned} 
\boldsymbol{r}_0 \times \boldsymbol{p} &= \frac{ \left(  \boldsymbol{p} \times \boldsymbol{L} \right) \times \boldsymbol{p}} { \| \boldsymbol{p} \|^2 } = \frac{ \boldsymbol{p} \times \left( \boldsymbol{L} \times \boldsymbol{p} \right)}{\|\boldsymbol{p}\|^2} \\
 &= \frac{ \boldsymbol{L} \left( \boldsymbol{p}\cdot \boldsymbol{p} \right) - \boldsymbol{p} \left( \boldsymbol{p} \cdot \boldsymbol{L} \right)}{\|\boldsymbol{p}\|^2} = \frac{ \| \boldsymbol{p} \|^2}{\|\boldsymbol{p}\|^2} \boldsymbol{L} \\ & = \boldsymbol{L}\;\;\checkmark
\end{aligned} $$
and note that $\boldsymbol{p}\cdot \boldsymbol{L} = 0$ by the definition of $\boldsymbol{L}$


Impulse
Now consider an impulse $\boldsymbol{J}$ acting on two bodies with momentum $\boldsymbol{p}_1$ and $\boldsymbol{p}_2$ and total momentum $\boldsymbol{p}_1 + \boldsymbol{p}_2$

The change in total linear momentum is zero, and the total final momentum is unchanged from the initial total momentum
$$ \begin{array}{c|c|c}
\text{object} & \text{change in momentum} & \text{final momentum} \\
\hline
\text{body 1} & {-}\boldsymbol{J} & \boldsymbol{p}_1 - \boldsymbol{J} \\
\text{body 2} & {+}\boldsymbol{J} & \boldsymbol{p}_2 + \boldsymbol{J} \\
\hline
\text{combined} & 0 & \boldsymbol{p}_1 + \boldsymbol{p}_2
\end{array}$$
The final total momentum is $(\boldsymbol{p}_1 - \boldsymbol{J}) + (\boldsymbol{p}_2 + \boldsymbol{J}) = \boldsymbol{p}_1 + \boldsymbol{p}_2$

With an assumption that the position of the object does not change during the impulse (that the impulse is short-lived) then the total final angular momentum is also unchanged.

The point of impact is designated $\boldsymbol{r}$ and is common with the two bodies.
Total angular momentum before impact is
$$ \boldsymbol{L}_{\rm tot} = \boldsymbol{r}\times \boldsymbol{p}_1 + \boldsymbol{r} \times \boldsymbol{p}_2 = \boldsymbol{r} \times ( \boldsymbol{p}_1 + \boldsymbol{p}_2) \tag{3}$$
Total angular momentum after the impact is
$$ \boldsymbol{r}\times ( \boldsymbol{p}_1 - \boldsymbol{J}) + \boldsymbol{r} \times ( \boldsymbol{p}_2 + \boldsymbol{J}) = \boldsymbol{r}\times ( \boldsymbol{p}_1 + \boldsymbol{p}_2 ) \;\;\checkmark$$


In summary, an impulse acts on a line of action that is preserved during its action and so angular momentum is also preserved if linear momentum is preserved (the $\boldsymbol{p}_1 + \boldsymbol{p}_2$ part above).

thanks this is really interesting but how does it relate to the discussion I quoted in my question? it seems that a small impulse does not cause any change to $L$  regardless its direction  provided it is short-lived enough? how does this relate to the other answers that say that the variation in p and the variation in L are infinitesimals of the same order?

put in other words, what are the two bodies in my scenario? and why are you assuming that the impulse conserves total momentum? do you consider it a force internal to the system? what if I "nudge" the orbiting body with a small external imput.what is r, the point of impact?

I'll attempt to sum up here my understanding in a "community wiki" fashion. Anyone who reads this and thinks it can be improved please edit / comment.
The definition of Lagrange stability (given few lines below in the text) goes like this:

Let $\bf{L}$ be fixed. A circular orbit is called (Lagrange) stable if for every $\epsilon > 0$ there exists $\delta > 0$ such that, for any initial data $r(0), \dot{r}(0)$ such that $|r(0) − r_c| < \delta, |\dot{r}(0)| < \delta $, it holds that $|r(t) − r(0)| < \epsilon $, for every $t \in \mathbb{R}$.

My understanding is that the discussion above about the small negligible changes to $\bf{L}$ aims at justifying the following expected hand waving description of stability:
a circular orbit $O_1$ is stable if we can keep the orbiting body close to $O_1$ as much as the we want with a small enough nudge
The second definition should be equivalent to the first one because a small short impulse will either:

keep the same $\bf{L}$ and slightly displace the body off orbit (if the impulse is along $\bf{e_{r}}$)

change $\bf{L}$ slightly (so that the body will have to abandon $O_1$) either in magnitude (if the impulse is along $\bf{e_{\phi}}$) or direction (when parallel to $\bf{L}$

a "combination" of the previous cases


Now, if we are in situation 1, the definition of Lagrange stability itself automatically guarantees that the body will stay close to $O_1$.
For situation 2, we assume that for $\bf{L}+\bf{\delta L}$, with $\bf{\delta L}$ small enough, there exists a stable circular orbit $O_2$ close to the original one . Of course this assumption would need to be proved formally; but that should be the case if the potential function is regular enough.
That said, applying the definition of Lagrange stability to $O_2$ would guarantee that the body will not move too far from $O_2$, hence from $O_1$.
As pointed out in an answer, in case the impulse is an action-reaction of the two interacting bodies (I assume here we talk about a situation like a planet and its satellite) the angular momentum is automatically conserved.
Hope all of this makes sense and thanks you all for your contributions.

This is a comment that got too long. OP's question is very good. The quoted paragraph of infinitesimal estimates on p. 188 in Ref. 1 seems like an anticlimax after introducing a rigorous Def. 4.6 of Lyapunov stability on p. 151 for first-order systems (by rewriting the 2nd-order EOM as a couple of 1st-order ODEs.)
Apparently the quoted paragraph served as an unsatisfactory heuristic argument for declaring in the very next paragraph (Def. 5.2) that the angular momentum ${\bf L}$ is fixed, and instead study the weaker notion of Lagrange stability (still assuming ${\bf L}$ is fixed).
See also this related Phys.SE post.
References:

A. Fasano & S. Marmi, Analytic Mechanics, 2006; p. 188.


thanks for your comments. I've tried to be costructive here and I've summed up my understandings in a collaborative wiki answer... on the other hand  I still think that Fasano Marmi's Analytical Mechanics is a good book and very clear. only that passage is a bit weak compared to the rigor of the rest of the text.
